# traverse all the disks or get hd_struct by device name in kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, disk

I'm writing a kernel module(on linux 2.6.32), to get the `disk_stats` of all the disks(not partition) in use. In other words, I'm getting the data just like what `/sys/block/sda/stat` shows, but in kernel module.

(NOTE: By 'not partition', I mean we just handle `sda` and ignore `sda1/sda2/etc`, for example.)

Is there anything like `for_each_netdev` or `for_each_possible_cpu` for block device? Beacuse there may be multiple disks and I need a way to traverse them. Or at the latest, how can I get the related data structure with the block device's name(like `sda`)?

I know we can get a disk's `disk_stats` from the disk's `hd_struct`, but how could I get this `hd_struct`?

Please help me. thanks.

Comment: I have read linux2.6.32/block/genhd.c, and I know the content of file /sys/block/sda/stat is generated by `diskstats_show`. But how does the second argument come?

Comment: take look at disk_seqf_start

Comment: @Sasi thanks for answering. I have seen `disk_seqf_start`, but in its implemention, it uses variable `block_class` and `disk_type`. `block_class` is defined here([link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/genhd.c#L1110)) and it hasn't been `EXPORT_SYMBOL`. `disk_type` has been defined as static, see here([link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/genhd.c#L1124)). So I cann't accessed them in my own module. Maybe there's no solution to my problem at all -:(

Comment: Why not define disk_type and block_class in your module and reuse the code from genhd if needed?.

Comment: @Sasi Because I'm not sure whether I can define the identical ones. In genhd.c, `block_class` has been init in `genhd_device_init`([link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/genhd.c#L899)), and `disk_type` has been init with several functions who call other function.([link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/genhd.c#L1124)) It quite   complicated and I can't be certain whether I can get the same ones.